# Spring LdapRepository: empty attribute when Group on AD has more than 1500 records

Tags: spring, active-directory, spring-data, ldap

I have an application in Java Spring Boot 2 that uses Spring Data and LdapRepository to perform operations on Active Directory.

Specifically, my application needs to remove users from some groups eg (CN=all-GLOBAL,OU=orggroups,OU=Groups,....) present on AD.

Once the user to be acted upon has been identified, the removal involves the elimination (from the single group) of the following attributes

"**memberUid**" and "**member**"

ex:

```
member: CN=john.doe,ou=People,ou=....
memberUid: john.doe
```

On groups with less than 1500 members everything works correctly, while with groups with a number of members greater than 1500 the result of the call on AD returns an empty array.

For groups with more than 1500 members I noticed that the attribute is not

```
member: CN=john.doe,ou=People,ou=....
```

but

```
member;range=0-1499: CN=john.doe,ou=People,ou=....
```

this is my model class used by LdapRepository

```
@Entry(objectClasses = { "posixGroup" })
@Data
public class PosixGroupAD implements Persistable<Name>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Name id;

    @Attribute(name = "cn")
    private String cn;

    @Attribute(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Attribute(name = "member")    
    private Set<String> members;
    
    @Attribute(name = "memberUid")
    private Set<String> memberUids;

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.isNew;
    }

    public void setIsNew(boolean isNew) {
        this.isNew = isNew;
    }

}
```

but when I call

```
List<PosixGroupAD> posixGroups = posixGroupADRepository.findAll();

it happens that the call posixGroup.getMembers():

for (PosixGroupAD posixGroup : posixGroups) {  

    // less than 1500 members returns the array with the values
    posixGroup.getMembers()

    // more than 1500 members returns empty array []
    // so I can't delete the user via "member" and "memberUid"
    posixGroup.getMembers()

}
```

Suggestions on how to resolve this issue and why, in the case of more than 1500 members, members is empty []?

Thank you

Comment: There is [an open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/561) for this on Spring LDAP. Their is a possible solution mentioned in that issue as well, you could try that, else you are out of luck with regards to Spring Data and would need to implement it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Spring LDAP's `IncrementalAttributeMapper`? See their documentation section [Incremental Retrieval of Multi-Valued Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/3.1.x/reference/#incremental-retrieval-of-multi-valued-attributes):

> When there are a very large number of attribute values (>1500) for a specific attribute, Active Directory typically refuses to return all these values at once. Instead, the attribute values are returned according to the Incremental Retrieval of Multi-valued Properties method. Doing so requires the calling part to inspect the returned attribute for specific markers and, if necessary, make additional lookup requests until all values are found.
>
> Spring LDAP’s `org.springframework.ldap.core.support.DefaultIncrementalAttributesMapper` helps when working with this kind of attributes, as follows:
>
> ```java
> Object[] attrNames =  new Object[]{"oneAttribute", "anotherAttribute"};
> Attributes attrs = DefaultIncrementalAttributeMapper.lookupAttributes(ldapTemplate, theDn,
> attrNames);
> ```
>
> The preceding example parses any returned attribute range markers and makes repeated requests as necessary until all values for all requested attributes have been retrieved.